# adding text below image in coverflow in android

Tags: android, listview, coverflow, galleryview

I am developing an android application Tft.

I had downloaded coverflow example from this URL: [Android Coverflow Widget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

I want to place text below all the image in that list. How can i do this?

Comment: hi link is not working . it shows page not found .

Comment: paste the link in google.It will show u,,,Chirag,,

Comment: Chirag ,,,,u got the link open??

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem with coverflow widget.

After some research, came up with a solution of using `canvas.drawText()` method.

Add `canvas.drawText(String, origin-x, origin-y, paint)` in the method where you draw the reflected image.

eg: `canvas.drawText("helloo", 10, 10, new Paint())`